# If condition triggering char

Tags: arrays, c

I wrote a code to print a transposed 2-D array in matrix form.
For this I added a condition so that if the user enters the dimension of array less than '1' it will print "invalid dimension" and exit. But when I enter a character, this condition is triggered. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
int i,j,arr[10][10],n,n1;
printf("Enter the dimensions of the array\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
scanf("%d",&n1);
if(n<1||n1<1){
    printf("Invalid dimension\n");
    exit(0);
}
else

printf("Enter the elements for matrix\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
    }
}
printf("Printing matrix\n");

 for(i=0;i<n1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        printf("  %d  ",arr[j][i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: When you enter a character both `scanf` functions will fail because they require an int input. On failure `scanf` will not set `n` and `n1`. And since both the variables are not initialised the `if` check is using indeterminate values resulting in Undefined Behaviour. Always check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: @kaylum: According to [§6.3.2.1 ¶2 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p2), the behavior is only undefined if the address of the uninitialized variable was not taken. However, in this case, the address was taken.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Bringing that language lawyer point up here is just going to muddy the waters. The point is that the variable is used uninitialised and the result of the `if` is thus not predictable. I've seen that part of the C11 standard quoted and I don't really want to argue about it as I'm not language lawyer. But consider a counter point in Annex J.2 which gives examples of Undefined Behaviour including: *The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate*.

Comment: Got it! Thankyou guys! :D